# continuity of a function of two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let  $$  F : \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$$

with 
$\mathbb{X} = \begin{pmatrix} x  \\ y \end{pmatrix}$

$$
    F(\mathbb{X)}=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  \text{ 0 when x $\in \mathbb{Q}$ and y $\in \mathbb{Q}$}\\
                 \text{1 else }\\
                       \
                \end{array}
              \right.
  $$

My question is that  equivalent  to

$ F(\mathbb{X)}=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  \text{ 0 when x $\in \mathbb{Q}$ and y $\in \mathbb{Q}$}\\
                 \text{1  when x $\in \mathbb{R\backslash Q}$ and y $\in \mathbb{Q}$  }\\
                  \text{1  when x $\in \mathbb{Q}$ and y $\in \mathbb{R\backslash Q}$ }\\
                  \text{1  when x $\in \mathbb{R\backslash Q}$ and y $\in \mathbb{R\backslash Q}$  }\\
                \end{array}
              \right.
  $

if so  then  how to  proof that F is not continuous in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: 1) Your formulation is equivalent. 2) In order to show "not continuous", you just need one "counterexample". Since this is about numbers being rational/irrational, maybe come up with rationals numbers converging to an irrational, or vice versa. 3) If you have a problem with the fact this is about a 2-dimensional domain, try to formulate and solve the problem for a 1-dimensional domain ($\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$) first

Comment: Plz tell me if thqt correct i will handel the case when f(x)= 1 all those 3 cases can be resovled in the same way let $X_{0}$= (a,b) with a $\in \mathbb{R\backslashQ}$ and b$ \in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: so lets say that f is continuious in $X_{0}$ then exists a $ \epsilon$ and $\delta$ so that : let $\epsilon = 0,5$ 
$\abs{f(x) -f($X_{0}$)}< \epsilon and \norm{\abs{x}-\abs{$X_{0}$}}< \delta $ $\abs{x1 -a} < \delta$ $a-\delta <x1<a+\delta $ because $a-\delta $ and $a+\delta $ \in \mathbb{R} $ then can be x1 \in \mathbb{Q}$ analog to x2 then x=(x1,x2) $\in \mathbb{Q^2}$ \ Rightarrow $\abs{f(x)-f($X_{0}$)}$= $\abs{0-1}<0,5 $ $\Rightarrow $that is not possible $\Rightarrow $then f is not in $X_{0}$ continuous

Comment: It seems you have the right idea, but it is hard to tell with all the LaTeX things going wrong.

Comment: how can i write  absolute value and norme vecteur value here ?

Comment: absolute value: $\left| x-y\right|$ is made by \left| x-y\right|
norm: $\Vert x\Vert$ is made by \Vert x\Vert

Comment: Plz tell me if that correct, i will handel the case when f(x)= 1 all those 3 cases can be resovled in the same way let  $X_{0}$= (a,b) with$ a \in  \mathbb{R\textbackslash{Q}}$ and b$\in \mathbb{Q }$

Comment: so let s say that F is cotinuious in $X_{0}$ then  exists an $\epsilon$ and a $\delta$ so that : 
let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\left| f(X)-f(X_{0})\right| < \epsilon$ 
 and$ \vert \left|X\right| - \left|X_{0}\right| \vert < \epsilon$

Comment: $\left|x1 -a\right| < \delta$  $\Rightarrow (a- \delta) <x1 < (a+\delta) $
because $ (a- \delta) and  (a+\delta) $are $\in \mathbb{R}$  then  can  be x1 $\in \mathbb{Q}$ , the  same to x2 then  will X =(x1,x2)$ \in \mathbb{Q^2}$
$\Rightarrow  \left|f(x) -f(X_{0})\right| =\left| 0 -1\right| <0.5 \rightarrow $ that is not possible$ \rightarrow$ f is  not in $X_{0}$ Continuious for all $X_{0} \in \mathbb{(R\Q*Q)}$
is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

(If you are familiar with Connectedness)

Suppose $F$ was continuous, then image of connected set would be connected.

Consider the connected subset $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ of $\Bbb R^2$. Then $F([0,1] \times [0,1])=\{0,1\}$ and $\{0,1\}$ is not a connected subset of $\Bbb R$.

EDIT: In fact $\Bbb R^2$ is connected. But the image $F(\Bbb R^2)=\{0,1\}$ is not.